# Puxar elemento que tiver um atributo especifico com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com uma pagina cujo há quatro Divs, todas com a class .coloritem:

```
<div class="coloritemSelected" style="background: Vermelho;" onclick="javascript:showOptionsFor('Vermelho');">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="coloritem" style="background: red;" onclick="javascript:showOptionsFor('Azul');">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="coloritem" style="background: red;" onclick="javascript:showOptionsFor('Púrpura');">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="coloritem" style="background: red;" onclick="javascript:showOptionsFor('Laranja');">&nbsp;</div>
```

Gostaria de saber se tem como pegar somente a div que tenha tal cor, como a Vermelha e alterá-la para que tenha o `background: red;`

Estava a testar com esse codigo, porém ele acaba colocando a cor em todas as Divs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var item = $('.coloritem');
    var background = item.attr('style');
    if (background == 'background:Vermelho;') {
        $(item).css('background', 'red');
    };
});
```

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Tem algum evento de clique por exemplo que dispare essa mudança?

Comment: Estava pensando em realizar esse evento quando a pagina carregar, já que ao carrega-la as divs aparecem em branco.

Comment: Coloca as cores em um atributo do tipo `data` ao invés do `style`, por exemplo: `data-cor="vermelho"`, daí no *jQuery* você lê essa propriedade através do `$('.coloritem').data('cor')`...

Comment: Pera tu vai rodar um JS pra alterar as cores quando a pagina carregar? Porque não cria uma class pra cada cor e ja deixa nas divs certas?

Comment: @PauloImon a questão é que a pagina da qual estou trabalhando é o template de uma loja, e já procurei onde fica a localização do elemento no diretorio, porém não encontrei (as paginas estão todas separadas, com a extensão .tpl)

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer que aconteça, quando a pessoa clicar no showOptionsFor, o que deve ocorrer?

Comment: Obrigado por todos que tentaram ajudar, consegui encontrar o local de origem do arquivo, com isso consegui fazer o que planejava com a dica que o @PauloImon deu.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá.
Pra entender por que todas as divs estão sendo afetadas, basta entender essa linha do seu código:

```
var item = $('.coloritem');
```

Se você der um `console.log(item);` vai notar um Array de itens, por que este seletor recuperou todos os itens que tenham como class  `.coloritem`.

Pra resolver isso, você precisará usar algo que filtre exatamente o elemento que você quer. Felizmente o jQuery tem exatamente o método `filter();`
Este método recebe uma string que será utilizada como seletor, daí o retorno dele será apenas os objetos que tenham tal seletor dentro de um seletor existente.. Ou seja:

```
var item = $('.coloritem');
var t = item.filter('style["background: Vermelho;"]'); // aqui terá apenas o item cujo style seja background Vermelho
```

Agora você pode alterar a cor do objeto `t` normalmente.

Espero ter ajudado.

(Veja o comentário do Paulo Imon. Vai ficar mais elegante a solução)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, não conhecia esse método do jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Até tem como porém seu exemplo está errado, e você esta pegando apenas 1 elemento com a classe coloritem veja esse exemplo, onde percorro todos os elementos que possuem essa classe e verifico se existe determinada string, se existir substituo:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="coloritem coloritemSelected" style="background: Vermelho;" onclick="javascript:showOptionsFor('Vermelho');">&nbsp;
</div>
<div class="coloritem" style="background: red;" onclick="javascript:showOptionsFor('Azul');">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="coloritem" style="background: red;" onclick="javascript:showOptionsFor('Púrpura');">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="coloritem" style="background: red;" onclick="javascript:showOptionsFor('Laranja');">&nbsp;</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var item = $('.coloritem');
        $.each(item, function() {
            
            if($(this).attr('style') === 'background: Vermelho;') {
                $(this).attr('style','background: red;')
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```